# How to get Stock Fundamental time series data?

Tags: equities, data, historical-data, fundamentals

I need key Stock Fundamentals like in http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=KO+Key+Statistics

But that page shows only the last quarter data, I need to analyze how that data has changed over past years.
Yahoo provides Historical Data only for prices, where to find it for fundamentals also?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a friend studying at almost any university you can get access to WRDS.
Inside WRDS just go to Compustat which has all the info you need for dates since 1950.

Comment: No, I tried but unfortunately my university is not listed.

Comment: Is there someone who could share its username & pwd?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. But if you let me know what you need I might quickly pull an excel with it.

Comment: i'd like to do this: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18773/idea-search-for-unprofitable-companies-and-invest-when-turn-profitable

Answer (score 2):

There are two mainly (good) free sources available online:

- [wolphramalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)
- [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/)

They report the mainly market and fundamental data, so you will not find any particular fundamental accounting ratio. In the case you need particular ratio or data, you should get some better financial data provider, as, for instance, Bloomberg or Thompson Reuters.

Comment: I tried both but I didn't find time series for Fundamentals. I think access to Bloomberg professional will cost to me thousands of $. I'm just want to do some personal research

Comment: @sparkle, what data do you need for?

Comment: Equities. Stocks. US and european stocks.

Comment: This page is what I'm looking for, but it's yearly data. I need quarterly. http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=KO&region=usa&culture=en-US

Comment: I meant dividends, EP ratio and so on. Anyway, look at https://www.quandl.com/data/DMDRN?keyword=

Comment: You might also try Quandl's Raymond database which provides income, balance sheet, and cash flow data for the past five years.  For example, for [MSFT quarterly dividends](https://www.quandl.com/data/RAYMOND/MSFT_DIVIDENDS_PER_SHARE_COMMON_STOCK_PRIMARY_ISSUE_Q-MSFT-Dividends-per-Share-Common-Stock-Primary-Issue)

Comment: @sparkle look at those new comments!

Answer (score 0):

[Intrinio](http://intrinio.com) provides that data historically. You can get it in a dynamic Excel spreadsheet if you install the [Excel add-in](https://intrinio.com/tutorial/excel) or [via API](https://intrinio.com/tutorial/web_api) if you are a developer. Here is what it looks like in Excel:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCdSQQsGiHE&t=13s

In Excel, you can use pre-defined templates just by entering a ticker:
[image: Enter a ticker in Excel]
[image: That gives you the entire statement history]

This gives you a lot of flexibility to modify the cells and everything is basically done for you. If you are a developer, you can just use the API directly, the Excel add-in is a wrapper of the API.

Answer (score 0):

All of the data is easily available from https://simfin.com/. The site has now been updated and now standardized company statements for over 2000 US equities and financial ratios are available (as well as their historical development).